# Logging In with Windows User Account Credentials

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

My client has just said that he would like me to implement a feature where when he starts up the app I made for him, he would simply like to enter his Windows User Account username and password to login to the app.

I've read a tutorial about this somewhere last year, but for the life of me, can't find it anywhere now. And a few google searches don't reveal anything for me.

Are there any docs/tuts/articles on this still hanging around somewhere?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly does cause difficulties for you? 
Creating a logon form, impersonation a thread, impersonating an access to a network resource?

Anyway check [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184%28VS.85%29.aspx) function

Comment: Just what I need. Thank you Shrike. :)

Answer (score 2):

Um, they already entered those credentials when they logged onto their current session. In which case, just the fact that the user has attempted to run the app indicates they have permission to use it.

Comment: It *may* indicate they have permission to use the laptop. But it does not indicate that a person not related to his business in anyway has permission to use an app that manages 90% of his business from his personal laptop. And he's stated that nobody has the credentials for his laptop, however he refuses to simply lock it while he's AFK (Away from keyboard).

Comment: Thats a security sham then. If someone has illicit access to the logged in session they can access all the relevant files. The only way to achieve any kind of actual security in this situation would be to apply a different accounts ACL to the files. I assume that its not just the application, but some data files that are the actual issue here?

Comment: Correct. I don't understand why he just won't create a separate, new username and password just for this application. And I don't really understand why he wants it to be this way, but he specifically stated he wants it to be like this. So I'm figuring he's read up on it? Re: Data files; There are a lot of files that are being read and written to, but they're all located either in the database, or on the server. The only files that are accessed from within the application are Usage Log files and a Contact list for customers.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on whether that user is in an Active Directory or in the local user store, but this should help you get started.

http://geekswithblogs.net/Ramaraju/archive/2009/07/14/windows_authentication_in_winform_application.aspx

Comment: This would work for both cases. In the example from the provided link, the domain may be null, empty, . (dot) and probably machine name (but not sure about it) when providing local user credentials.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I only have experience with domain users.